# Javascript : Select Element in URL with multiple instance of the same element

Tags: javascript

i need to retrieve a value from an URL in JS, my problem is in this url, the element is repeated at least twice with different value. What i need is the last one.

Example :
http://randomsite.com/index.php?element1=random1&element2=random2&element1=random3
and what i want is "random3" and NOT "random1"

I've tried url.match(/.*(\&|\?)element1=(.*?)\&/)[2];
But it always gives me the first one :(

I don't have the possibility to change how the url is written as this is for a browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ws = "http://randomsite.com/index.php?element1=random1&element2=random2&element1=random3",
    input = ws.split("?")[1].split("&"),
    dataset = {},
    val_to_find = "element1";

    for ( var item in input){
        var d = input[item].split("=");
        if (!dataset[d[0]]){  dataset[d[0]] = new Array(); dataset[d[0]].push(d[1]); }
        else{
            dataset[d[0]].push(d[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log("item: ", dataset[val_to_find][dataset[val_to_find].length -1]);
    return dataset[val_to_find][dataset[val_to_find].length -1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wMuHW/

Comment: i can write up a fiddle if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Take the minimum value (other than -1) from `urlString.lastIndexOf("&element1=")` and `urlString.lastIndexOf("?element1=")`, then use `urlString.substring`.

Or alternately, split the string up:

```
var parts = urlString.split(/[?&]/);
```

...which will give you:

```
[
    "http://randomsite.com/index.php",
    "element1=random1",
    "element2=random2",
    "element1=random3"
]
```

...then start looping from the end of the array finding the first entry that starts with `element=` and grabbing the bit after the `=` (again with `substring`).

Answer (score 0):

You could;

```
for (var result, match, re = /[&?]element1=(.+?)(\&|$)/g; match = re.exec(url);) {
    result = match[1];
}

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Id try keeping a nested array of duplicate elements

```
 function parseQueryString() {
    var elements = {},
            query = window.location.search.substring(1),
            vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split('='),
               key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]),
               value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

       if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          elements[key].push(value);
       }
       else {
          elements[key] = [value];
       }
    }
 }
```

Used on: `www.example.com?element1=hello&element2=test&element1=more`

Would give you the object:

```
{
   element1: [
      "hello",
      "more"
   ],
   element2:[
      "test"
   ]
}
```